# how to list numbers between two numbers java spark datafrme

Tags: java, regex, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

dataframe input:

[image]

Requird dataframe Output
[image]

if input file having colone we need find beetween number 
ex:
1:10 ->1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10

it is posible do with regex . i dont get clear picture for that please some one help for that

Comment: Please provide us with some code that you have tried already - otherwise your question will not receive any answers/help

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
UDF:
def myudf2=(input:String)=>{
    val regex = "('\\d+':'\\d+')".r
    val out = new ListBuffer[String]()
    input.replaceAll("'", "").split(",").map(x=>{
      if(x.matches("(\\d+:\\d+)")){
        val colon = x.split(":")
        out += (colon(0).toInt to colon(1).toInt).mkString(", ")
      } else {
        out += x
      } 
    })
    out.mkString(",").replaceAll("\\[|\\]", "")
  }

val df = Seq((1,"'1':'5','6','7':'10'"),(2,"'1':'6','7','8':'12'")).toDF("id","number")
scala> df.show
+---+--------------------+
| id|              number|
+---+--------------------+
|  1|'1':'5','6','7':'10'|
|  2|'1':'6','7','8':'12'|
+---+--------------------+
val myCostumeudf = udf(myudf2)
scala> val outDF = df.withColumn("output", myCostumeudf(df("number")))
scala> outDF.show(5,false)
+---+--------------------+---------------------------------------+
|id |number              |output                                 |
+---+--------------------+---------------------------------------+
|1  |'1':'5','6','7':'10'|1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10          |
|2  |'1':'6','7','8':'12'|1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12  |
+---+--------------------+---------------------------------------+
```

Try something like above.